# Sharepoint causing 2nd login when downloading documents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have Sharepoint 2007 setup with Integrated Windows Authentication and it works fine for the most part. When users access the site, the dialog comes up and has them type in their username/password information and that works well. The problem I am having is that once they go to a document library and try to download a file, it re-asks them for their login information. Is there a way to turn off this 2nd authentication request?

EDIT: On Windows 7 with IE 8 and Office 2010, it does not prompt me the 2nd time. On Windows XP with IE 6 and Office 2007, it does prompt me a 2nd time.

Comment: What browser is being used for access?  Is this an internet or intranet site?

Comment: Its IE 6 and I think its setup as a Extranet(if that is an option) or Internet site. Its accessible from outside, but uses AD to authenticate.

Comment: Have a look at this question:  http://serverfault.com/questions/44194/internet-explorer-8-causing-login-prompt-connecting-to-sharepoint-2007-from-sepa

Comment: If it answers your question, we can close this one as a dupe.  I know that question has to do with IE8, but I think it will also help your situation.

Comment: GregD: That answer would get rid of the 1st login while on the domain, but it still asks for the username/password when opening the Word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with IE on Windows 7 (and Vista) where you click to open an Office 2007 document in SharePoint and you are prompted again for your username and password despite already being logged into the portal.  This does not affect Windows XP.

Detailed information and the fix can be found on the Microsoft site [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280/en-us):